# How do I hide the browser's scollbars?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the browser scrollbars. Is there a way to do that using JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: I want a date with Nadine Velazquez.

Comment: @Pekka: Thanks for editing your comment and giving the full name. Because when I wanted to Google with the first name, I got lots of suggestion and did not understand which one you meant. Now that I got the full name, I can search to the point

Comment: @Sarwar she is *great*. Plays a mexican maid in [My Name Is Earl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Name_Is_Earl) . Had a crush on her ever since :)

Comment: @Stephan you know what I'm talking about! Jump jump jump around....

Answer (score 5):

No JavaScript needed:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer, I add a link to overflow property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: @Fran Don't support them by any means... In case you have not read: http://w3fools.com/